# Not able to import node module "file-system" in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I am trying to import fs-jetpack into my component.ts file.
I did "npm install file-system"

In the component.ts file, I tried putting

- import * as fs from 'file-system';
- import fs from 'file-system';

It did not work.

I am using webpack to bundle the application.
When I run "webpack" from the console, It throws an error:

ERROR in ./app/components/addImage/addImage.component.ts
(6,21): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'file-system'.

I also tried:

- Having the below in index.html file

  System.config({
   map: {
          'file-system': 'node_modules/file-system/file-system.js'
      } 
  });

  - import fs = require('file-system');

Comment: Apart from your current problem, if you run Angular in the browser, sandboxing will never allow you get access to the file system on the client.

Comment: I am using electron to run application native to system.